Grabbing subject email using powerautomate
List structure
Country-Single line of text
customer-Single line of Text
Incoming Email details
Subject: customerno-123,Location-USA,Region-Florida,Department-Sharepoint,Type-Active
I need to grab the values of customerno,location,region,department,Type values into sharepoint list dynamically based on email subject values and subject template will be as per the below one.
Email Subject: customerno-123,Location-USA,Region-Florida,Department-Sharepoint,Type-Active
Next i need to create folder structure and store email attachment into document library based on subject values
example : Year/Month/Location/Region/Department/Type
Document library sample
2024/July/USA/Florida/Sharepoint/Active/attachment1.docx
Kindly help
